# How to specify nu=infinity for Matern kernel in Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm trying to create a Matern kernel in Sklearn with the parameter nu set to infinity.

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
import numpy as np
kernel = Matern(nu=float('inf'))
a = np.random.randn(5)[:,np.newaxis]
b = a
kernel(a,b)
```

When I run this code, I get an error message:

> "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
>    K *= tmp ** self.nu"

How else then may I specify the parameter nu as infinity in a Matern kernel? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern.html) seems to suggest that `inf` is a valid value for `nu` [the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py#L1245) doesn't seem to account for that value, which is why you're seeing that error. However as the `nu` approaches infinity Matern kernel becomes equivalent to the squared exponential function, or the [`RBF`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html) in sklearn, so you can just use the following

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
import numpy as np
kernel = RBF()
a = np.random.randn(5)[:,np.newaxis]
b = a
kernel(a,b)
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. I have marked this as Answer, and upvoted :) Thanks.